# Errors on entity CrystalSystem

Tags: entity

Following the tutorial on [Exploring Symmetries of Crystal Systems](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/physics-and-chemistry-entities/exploring-symmetries-of-crystal-systems.html?product=mathematica) and using the code below:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; symmetryprops = {"Entity", 
  "RequiredPointGroupSymmetries", "CrystallographicPointGroups", 
  "CrystallographicSpaceGroups", "BravaisLattices", "LatticeSystems"};

symmetryheader = 
  StringReplace[
   Prepend[CommonName[
     EntityProperty["CrystalFamily", #] & /@ Rest[symmetryprops]], 
    CommonName[Entity["CrystalSystem"]]], "crystallographic" -> ""];

TextGrid[
 Prepend[MapAt[Length, 
   EntityValue["CrystalSystem", symmetryprops], {All, 3 ;; 5}], 
  symmetryheader], 
 Sequence[Dividers -> All, 
  Background -> {Automatic, {{LightBlue, None}}}]]
```

Mathematica gives me warning messages:

> Error:
> CommonName:Entity[CrystalSystem] is not an entity.
> StringReplace:Stringorlistofstringsexpectedatposition1inStringReplace[{CommonName[Entity[CrystalSystem]],requiredpointgroupsymmetry,crystallographicpointgroups,crystallographicspacegroups,Bravaislattice,latticesystems},crystallographic]

Why?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear here, the thing you are passing to `StringReplace` is not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CommonName` must be **mapped** over `x`

Replace `CommonName[Entity[CrystalSystem]]` with `CrystalSystem`

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 

symmetryprops = {"Entity", 
  "RequiredPointGroupSymmetries", "CrystallographicPointGroups", 
  "CrystallographicSpaceGroups", "BravaisLattices", "LatticeSystems"};

x = EntityProperty["CrystalFamily", #] & /@ Rest[symmetryprops];

symmetryheader =
 StringReplace[Prepend[CommonName /@ x, "CrystalSystem"], 
  "crystallographic" -> ""]

TextGrid[
 Prepend[MapAt[Length, 
   EntityValue["CrystalSystem", symmetryprops], {All, 3 ;; 5}], 
  symmetryheader], 
 Sequence[Dividers -> All, 
  Background -> {Automatic, {{LightBlue, None}}}]]
```

[image]